# Google sites: clicking top menu and display submenu on the side bar

Tags: sidebar, google-sites

I don't know if this is the right place to ask questions about Google sites. I wonder if it is possible for a Google site to have a horizontal menu on the top, and clicking one item of top menu would display its sub-menu on the side bar? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that! You have to add it on the page which you open with the horizontal menu. 
 Edit page -> Insert -> select sub-page listing.

In the sub-page listing you can choose from where and how many levels you want to show in the menu.
look at this [explanation](https://sites.google.com/site/sitetemplateinfo/tips/use-the-sub-page-listing-gadget) to get an ideia how to do it.

Comment: One more question: is it possible that if I click one item of the sub-page listing, the list will still remains on the page?

Comment: No, that is not possible, this sub-page listing always points to the active page. To have something like your suggesting you have to get into Google Apps Script.